# count of custom applications in salesforce

Tags: soql

How can we query total number of Custom Applications in the Salesforce Org?
I have tried it with SOQL query but its not giving expected output.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Post soql you tried

Comment: i have tried this query but its not giving exact output:  SELECT count() FROM AppMenuItem..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if by custom applications, you mean Connected apps or Apps. Either way, these queries should get you the results you need

Connected apps in your org -

```
SELECT Id, Parent.Profile.Name, SetupEntityId 
  FROM SetupEntityAccess 
 WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ConnectedApplication'
```

Custom applications in your org -

```
SELECT ApplicationId,  Description, Id, Label, Name 
  FROM AppMenuItem 
 WHERE Type = 'ConnectedApplication'
```